# почему int в скобочках? Что тут значат вопрос и двоеточие? Как это должно работать?

Tags: c++, c

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]  почему int в скобочках? Что тут значат вопрос и двоеточие?

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

int в скобках - приведение к типу int.

Вопрос и двоеточие - [тернарный оператор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). То есть всё выражение равноценно такому:

```
if (a > 0) {
    b = int(a + 0.5) 
} else {
    b = int(a - 0.5)
}
```

Comment: Спасибо))))))))))))))))))))))))

Comment: Да, Harry - кросавчег! Потому что будучи первым по рейтингу, не брезгует отвечать на довольно простые вопросы :-)

Answer (score 3):

Приведение вещественного числа (`double`) к типу `int` — те самые "круглые скобочки" — отбрасывает дробную часть числа.

Типа, `a = 1.42`

Выражение в круглых скобках дает 1.92, отбрасывание дробной части - 1, итог: 1.42 округлено до 1.

`a = 1.62`

Выражение в круглых скобках дает 2.12, отбрасывание дробной части - 2, итог: 1.62 округлено до 2.

Comment: А вопрос и двоеточие - тернарный оператор "арифметическое ИЛИ". Выражение аналогично такому: ```if (a>0) b=(int)(a+0.5) else b=(int)(a-0.5);```

Comment: Спасибо))))))))))))))0

Comment: Здравствуйте, Harry. Опоздал конечно, но что поделать. Поздравляю с 200k! За это время вы успели помочь многим, а кому-то может и помогли встать на путь истинный! Я рад, что есть такие люди как вы, которые просто хотят помочь другим, что у них очень хорошо получается. Удачи вам отпраздновать это достижение!